# What's the best way to show distinct values for a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to check the distinct values for a data frame and I know there are a way ways that I can do it. I'd like to look at the unique values for columns `rabbit`, `platypus` and `book`.

This is the first way

```
mydf
.select("rabbit", "platypus", "book")
.distinct
.show
```

This is the second way

```
mydf
.select("rabbit", "platypus", "book")
.distinct
.count
```

This is another way

```
 val rabbit = mydf.groupByKey(log => {
     val rabbit = mydf.rabbit
     rabbit
 }).count.collect

 val platypus = mydf.groupByKey(log => {
     val platypus = mydf.platypus 
     platypus
 }).count.collect

 val book = mydf.groupByKey(log => {
     val book = mydf.book 
     book
     }).count.collect
```

Comment: you can also try `.dropDuplicates()` or include columns into it as well `dropDuplicates(colNames)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`.collect`** will get all the results back to driver and cause OOM errors on big datasets.

Use `.distinct()` method and if you want count of distinct records then use `df.distinct().count()`.

Comment: Sounds like the third way is fastest if I replace count.collect with distinct.count

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help on this thread and others :)